# Banner rotation in JavaScript with animation using CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, banner

I have to write a simple HTML banner rotator in JavaScript with animated transition using CSS3. I came with this:

- HTML:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/banner.css" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/banner.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div><img src="img/banner1.jpg" alt="" id="banner" /></div>
      <script>window.onload = rotateAnimation('banner', 5000);</script>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
  #banner {
    animation-name: myfirst;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-play-state: running;
  }
  @keyframes myfirst {
    0%    {opacity: 0;}
    10%   {opacity: 1;}
    90%   {opacity: 1;}
    100%  {opacity: 0;}
  }
  ```
- JavaScript:

  ```
  var i = 0;
  var banners = new Array("img/banner1.jpg", "img/banner2.jpg", "img/banner3.jpg");

  function rotateAnimation(el, speed) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);

    elem.src = banners[i];

    setTimeout('rotateAnimation(\''+el+'\','+speed+')',speed);
    i++;

    if(i === banners.length) i = 0;
  }
  ```

But as I expected, the animation desynchronise itself and I don't know how to make this on one timer only.

Comment: Do you mean you want that to happen one time only? Or set the timer once and have it executed periodically?

If it's the latter, there's this thing called `setInterval`. Maybe use that instead? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: But that's still two timers. One in JS and one in CSS.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong....you're trying to periodically change the banner source every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I think I got it now. Didn't know that CSS transition property will work with JS.

Answer (score -1):

It didn't need an CSS3 animation. All it needed was JS script that change images and CSS3 trasition property. Didn't know that transitions work if JS is changing something.